# "Actions" alternative in Java (Eclipse) & GUI Recommendation

Tags: java, eclipse

I have recently switched from C# to JAVA, although I have a few questions.

I love how Visual Studio's GUI builder is laid out, is there a similar style one for JAVA?

Also in C#, you have an actions tab in the GUI designer, so you can click on an element and select properties and then select actions.. How is this done within Eclipse?

Comment: you might want to try netbeans' gui builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  try [WindowBuilder](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/06/21/window-builder-top-indigo-feature-2/) .It is moved to the  Eclipse project since eclipse 3.7  and is included in the **Java Developers version** by default. You can download the  **Java Developers version** at [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) or [install it as a plugin](http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php)  if you already have an eclipse but no WindowBuilder installed.